# Graphical representation of data

Tags: vb.net

I am totally new to the graphical representation of the data.  I want to make a progress report of students, based on marks achieved each year.
For example, in year 2005 marks were 750. in 2006 780 in 2007 800

I want to show it graphically.  Could any body give me code example?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using any third party tools like Crystal Reports or SQL-Server Reporting Services?

Comment: I want to show it in picture box and SSRS

Comment: For SSRS have a look here: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/beginning-sql-server-2005-reporting-services-part-3-the-chart-control/ or here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964128%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a label and set the Label.Width = intValue where intValue is the value you want to show (you can divide it by a factor to make sure it stays within a certain bound).  They you an play around with lable colors or backgrounds for different value ranges. E.g.

assume valuelist is the list of values

```
    Dim graphicallabels(n) As Label
    For i As Integer = 0 To valuelist.length
        graphicallabels(i) = New Label
        With graphicallabels(i)
            .Location = New Point(0, i * 2 * graphicallabels(i).Height)
            .Width = valuelist(i)
        End With
        If valuelist(i)> 50 Then
            graphicallabels(i).BackColor = Color.Green
        Else
            graphicallabels(i).BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Next
```

Note: untested code

HTH